# Close HttpURLConnection without closing InputStream?

Tags: java, sockets, http, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I have a method that opens a `HttpURLConnection` and then returns the `InputStream` from the response to the caller:

```
// Callers are responsible for closing the returned input stream
public InputStream get()
{
    final URL url= new URL("http://example.com");
    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    return httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
    
    // Don't close httpUrlConnection as that will close the returned input stream
    // which the caller is responsible for closing.
}
```

My problem is I cannot close the `HttpURLConnection` in this method as that would close the underlying `InputStream`, which the caller of this method  is responsible for closing. I have no control over the callers.

How bad is it that the `HttpUrlConnection` is not closed? Will it eventually be closed? Or should I implement some mechanism to close it after a period of time has elapsed? Or maybe copy/clone the `InputStream` and return the copy, which would allow me to close the `HttpURLConnection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to leave the connection open. That will present the risk of a resource leak. I would recommend creating a custom `InputStream` implementation that automatically closes the connection when the stream is closed:

```
public class HttpURLConnectionInputStream extends InputStream {

    private HttpURLConnection connection;
    private InputStream stream;

    public HttpURLConnectionInputStream(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.stream = connection.getInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return stream.read();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Then just pass your `HttpURLConnection` to the constructor and return the custom input stream:

```
public InputStream get() throws IOException {
    final URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpUrlConnection.connect();
    return new HttpURLConnectionInputStream(httpUrlConnection);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the close method, should we close the input stream first as well? E.g. @Override
        public void close() throws IOException
        {
            inputStream.close();
            httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
        }

Comment: @Rory I am looking at the JavaDoc and, to be honest, I cannot say for certain. It certainly wouldn't hurt to do both. Maybe surround each with its own try-catch?